# Условие в ansibe если X начинается с числа, которое начинается на единицу

Tags: ansible, condition-variable

Есть словарь users_list.yml вида

```
users:
   username: xxxx
   uid: 1111
   username: yyyy
   uid: 2221
```

Необходимо создать пользователя на Y сервере, uid которого начинается только с 1. Не могу понять какой фильтр использовать или подстановку, стандартные штуки типа 1.., 1[] и .т.д. не возврщают нужное значение uid. Интересует именно как сделать такой фильтр, которые проверяет первый символ в значении. Пока что у меня получилось только сделать если значение содержит 1. Не могу понять нужно ли мне использовать dic2item или regex. Буду рад совету, спасибо.

```
    vars_files:
       - /home/ansible/plays/inventory/vars/users_list.yml
       - /home/ansible/plays/inventory/vars/secret
    tasks:
      - name: add user to servers
        user:
          name: "{{ item.username }}"
          shell: /bin/bash
          group: wheel
          password: "{{ userpass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
        loop: "{{ users }}"
        when: item.uid is search("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Внезапно нашел решение, которое само собой оказалось достаточно простым:

```
when: (item.uid is regex("1[1-9]") and 'db' in group_names) or 
(item.uid is regex("2[1-9]") and 'webservers' in group_names)
```